# Issue with array.length syntax, using square brackets vs not for boolean operation?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm new to Java (please be gentle!) I'm working my way through Coding Bat's Java array questions and have found myself confused by the below section of code. I'm wondering why I cant use the below line:

```
if (nums.length >=1 && nums[0]==nums.length-1) {
```

the correct code is:

```
if (nums.length >=1 && nums[0]==nums[nums.length-1]) {
```

The coding bat question was basically return true if the first & last element of an array are the same AND the array has one or more elements.

What exactly is the difference between "

```
nums[nums.length-1]
```

and

```
nums.length-1
```

I tried searching for this and could find anything, apologies if this has been explained elsewhere.

The full code for reference:

```
public boolean sameFirstLast(int[] nums) {
   if (nums.length >=1 && nums[0]==nums[nums.length-1]) {
      return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

Comment: By the way, you can write that code without the conditional: `return nums.length >=1 && nums[0]==nums[nums.length-1];` is identical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*nums[nums.length-1]gives you the last element CONTAINED in the array*

Array can be of int, char, or whatever you want and the element is the same kind of the array.

*nums.length-1 gives you the length of the array minus 1*

It always is a int: the last position.

About code reference, Avoid check a condition to return the boolean result. Better:

```
public boolean sameFirstLast(int[] nums) {
   return (nums.length >=1 && nums[0]==nums[nums.length-1]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`nums[nums.length-1]`gives you the last element CONTAINED in the array.
`nums.length-1` gives you the length of the array minus 1 (i think this is a not really useful information :)